# How to change product (or quantity) on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

looking for some help here

so my plan is to have the option to change the product in the checkout page with some radio boxes.
[something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXJVs.png)

I've been trying to change the code bellow that is original to add fees.
My goal would be to have the different products on the radio box or at least that it change the quantity.

```
/**
 * @snippet       Dynamic Radio Buttons Fees - WooCommerce Checkout
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=79316
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 3.5.1
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */

// Part 1 
// Display Radio Buttons
// Uses woocommerce_form_field()

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice() {

   $chosen = WC()->session->get('radio_chosen');
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? WC()->checkout->get_value('radio_choice') : $chosen;
   $chosen = empty( $chosen ) ? 'no_option' : $chosen;

   $args = array(
   'type' => 'radio',
   'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
   'options' => array(
      'no_option' => 'No Option',
      'option_1' => 'Option 1 ($10)',
      'option_2' => 'Option 2 ($30)',
   ),
   'default' => $chosen
   );

   echo '<div id="checkout-radio">';
   echo '<h3>Customize Your Order!</h3>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'radio_choice', $args, $chosen );
   echo '</div>';

}

// Part 2 
// Add Fee and Calculate Total
// Based on session's "radio_chosen"

#2 Calculate New Total

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee', 20, 1 );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_fee( $cart ) {

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

  $radio = WC()->session->get( 'radio_chosen' );

  if ( "option_1" == $radio ) {
   $fee = 10;
  } elseif ( "option_2" == $radio ) {
   $fee = 30;
  }

  $cart->add_fee( __('Option Fee', 'woocommerce'), $fee );

}

// Part 3 
// Refresh Checkout if Radio Changes
// Uses jQuery

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_refresh() {
if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=radio_choice]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var p = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                    'radio': p,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// Part 4 
// Add Radio Choice to Session
// Uses Ajax

add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session' );

function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['radio']) ){
        $radio = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio'] );
        WC()->session->set('radio_chosen', $radio );
        echo json_encode( $radio );
    }
    die();
}
```

[code source](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-checkout-fees-based-on-radio-button-choice-ajax/)

Comment: What code you used to show this quantity list?

Comment: @Ali_k the one in the image is the one i'm trying to get.
I got close to that with the code that i'm trying to change

Comment: You'd need to write some base code for that so we can help you. Also, the image is not 100% logical, how would you handle multiple products in cart?

Comment: @Ali_k well I've been using the code up there - I'm trying to make it to change the product instead of the fee field || I don't want to handle multiple products. this will work with a landing page that will redirect to the checkout and then the user select the quantity there in the checkout

Comment: If you have user selected '15 items' for example and they got 3 products in cart, what would it do?

Comment: Users wont be able to do that - they will visit a landing page with only one button telling "buy now" - when they click they will be sent to the checkout and 1 item of that product will be added to the "cart" - then user will be able to change quantity in the radio buttons!

Answer (score 0):

You'll not use `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` in this case since you're not adding any fees but rather changing the quantity of the products available in user cart.

So assuming `no_option` means (1:default), `option_1` will change quantity to 10, and `option_2` will change quantity to 20, you'd change the function `bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session()` to look something like this:

```
function bbloomer_checkout_radio_choice_set_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['radio']) ){
        $radio = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio'] );
        $cart = WC()->cart;
        $cart_content = $cart->cart_contents;
        foreach ( $cart_content as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            if( 'no_option' === $radio ){
                $cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 1);
            }elseif( 'option_1' === $radio ){
                $cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 10);
            }elseif( 'option_2' === $radio ){
                $cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, 20);
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode( $_POST['radio'] ) ;
    die();
}
```

The above is just an example of how to manipulate the cart products quantity, you'd need change the options and the function to match your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I think it will solve my problem.
As soon as I can test, I leave feedback.
Now I have to try to understand why the values are not updated in the order review field